# Captain America in the past

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In the movie Endgame, Steve Rogers went back to the past to be with Peggy. Now Steve would know what would happen in upcoming years already like JFK assassination or terror attacks like 9/11. 
Do you think Captain america would have stopped it, starting with not allowing Dr zola to join S.H.I.E.L.D(who created Hydra inside SHIELD.)

OR rescuing Bucky from Hydra

Just a thought provoking question.

Comment: Those event’s may not have happened in Steve’s past, they only occluded this time around because he went back in time! Although I may be getting the time travel mechanics mixed up with another interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know - the only snippet we see of Steve's life in the past is of him dancing with Peggy - but I firmly believe it's unlikely, for three reasons.

Firstly, Steve specifically chose to remain in the past with Peggy *because* he wanted to leave behind his role as Captain America, and just live a normal, ordinary life. In other words, **Steve had retired from being Captain America**. Rescuing Bucky, or preventing HYDRA's infiltration of SHIELD, would require throwing himself back into the lifestyle that he had deliberately left behind - and potentially putting Peggy in harm's way.

Secondly, as with most time-travel media, a recurring theme in *Endgame* is that meddling in the past can have unintended consequences, such as Loki's escape with the Tesseract in the alternate 2012. Steve has no way of knowing what might happen if he doesn't let 9/11 or the JFK assassination run their course; perhaps something ten times worse will happen later on down the line.

Thirdly, as we know from the end of the film, Steve always planned to return to the original timeline anyway. So there would have been no point in stopping any of those disasters, because when he eventually returned to the original, unaltered timeline, they would still have happened.